# DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_by_name (Use wb[sheetname])

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I executed the below code, I received a warning that reads " DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_by_name (Use wb[sheetname])." To avoid receiving the warning and execute the code properly, how do I need to fix the code?? Please help.

```
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
wb.get_sheet_names()
```

Comment: Where did you get that code? If you're copying and pasting from sample code that you don't understand, using really old sample code is probably an especially bad idea, and you should look for newer examples. The examples in the `openpyxl` docs are both up-to-date and generally better than random stuff you find on some blog post by some guy.

Answer (score 23):

Use

```
wb.sheetnames
```

instead of

```
wb.get_sheet_names()
```

---

and use

```
wb["Sheet1"]
```

instead of

```
wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this

```
from openpyxl import *
source_file = load_workbook("file_path")
sheet = source_file["sheet_name"]

cell_value = sheet.cell(25,52) 
print(cell_value) 

source_file.close()
```

its work